# Safer way to add and delete crontab's job entries

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, cron

I have seen people recommending this to add a new entry:

```
(crontab -u user -l ; echo '$job') | crontab -u user -
```

And this to delete:

```
(crontab -l | grep -v '$regexp') | crontab -
```

But I'm not sure if this is safe. I believe there is a chance of a job being overwritten if there are "simultaneous" attempts to add or delete a job.

Is it safe? Or is there a safer way? Maybe using an individual file for each job placed in the /etc/cron.d/ directory?

Comment: I would say that depends on whether you're adding the job in a user's context or the system's context.

Comment: User crontabs are stored in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/` - at least on Debian. Running the `crontab -e` command causes the data to be copied to a temporary file and an editor invoked. So if you run two of the scripted updates simultaneously, it won't work as you expect.

Comment: A safer way would be to go into some SystemD machinations...

Comment: @roaima it’s as root in a docker container

Comment: Thanks. As root the way to go is definitely `/etc/cron.d/{package_or_application}`